# Postgis get a minimal area polygon that will cover all defined polygons

Tags: postgis

Let's say I got nearby buildings colored with blue. I need to get a polygon shape in pink like on the picture below:

[image]

Please advise how to achieve this.

Geometries are:

```
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
0103000020E6100000010000002B000000E96360FDD70C54C0AB73C8970DD639408644D3CED70C54C05B7EDB8E0DD6394005686AA1D70C54C005A1F1680DD6394068307D76D70C54C0129C27270DD63940212D5E4FD70C54C0937C71CB0CD63940B67C352DD70C54C04C159E580CD6394008570D11D70C54C01DCC30D20BD6394096B0C0FBD60C54C02318233C0BD63940F78BF2EDD60C54C0F3DEF59A0AD63940611E0AE8D60C54C0752599F309D639403A89E3ACD50C54C0CAC5D5B4A2D53940FC8204AFD50C54C05D956A0DA2D53940B5AB19B9D50C54C009C8C469A1D5394061EBD3CAD50C54C0862FF0CEA0D539402A38ACE3D50C54C0A62E7141A0D539406E84E502D60C54C065F5A5C59FD539409CC78B27D60C54C062993B5F9FD53940B2368950D60C54C01F0735119FD53940C27AA07CD60C54C0DCCA06DE9ED5394036F280AAD60C54C0EAFD20C79ED539409F76F4A0E20C54C035C5E4D29CD53940DD3C84D7E20C54C05ADB46DB9CD53940AF75DC0CE30C54C08B07D1059DD53940B1795B3FE30C54C059EA35519DD539409DBE776DE30C54C082B123BB9DD53940554FCE95E30C54C055EE58409ED53940709E27B7E30C54C05A09EADC9ED53940742B81D0E30C54C0892B0D8C9FD53940955512E1E30C54C035017848A0D539404EB85DE8E30C54C0EAB95F0CA1D53940BFF52A27E50C54C00D145F1C08D6394065B31125E50C54C0F5F7C9CE08D63940935E941AE50C54C03B55427D09D639401FFD0308E50C54C022F4B1220AD639406162EDEDE40C54C05D9744BA0AD63940BE6E12CDE40C54C09267723F0BD639403DF46CA6E40C54C0412068AE0BD6394050751A7BE40C54C08672D6030CD639400EDC634CE40C54C0DCE2413D0CD63940E841A81BE40C54C0DBD7FB580CD639405F4A53EAE30C54C0D71226560CD639400D2CDCB9E30C54C07F3FEA340CD63940E96360FDD70C54C0AB73C8970DD63940
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
0103000020E6100000010000002A000000A02CDD25E70C54C0C2326A6993D53940D7CFEEF8E60C54C0343DFE5D93D53940A11236CDE60C54C026FEF33693D539407003F8A3E60C54C02CB06BF592D539408F266D7EE60C54C05354609B92D539409C19B05DE60C54C06A30692B92D53940EBC0B842E60C54C0F396D5A891D539404CC64E2EE60C54C069C27F1791D53940C9591021E60C54C0E585B47B90D539400CE75E1BE60C54C0A944F8D98FD539401A2EF7F4E40C54C03C7C830329D5394080D598F6E40C54C08B99D75D28D53940D3EF68FFE40C54C0A11E32BB27D53940A4B82A0FE50C54C07A03901F27D539402CB27E25E50C54C04D86CB8E26D539406B2DD441E50C54C04A478E0C26D53940F5CA7663E50C54C0744D0F9C25D53940F95F9189E50C54C05AEA204025D53940E2E32FB3E50C54C08E9503FB24D53940A2034BDFE50C54C00DC27ACE24D5394052FDCB0CE60C54C0A7E38ABB24D53940DCD6170BED0C54C0704C58DD23D53940A0093639ED0C54C0290EA9E523D5394097833C66ED0C54C0DF36D40A24D539400D10CF90ED0C54C0EA7CC04B24D53940A21F9BB7ED0C54C0F8065EA624D5394096817AD9ED0C54C06B13121825D53940361061F5ED0C54C00F6D3D9D25D53940C2B2770AEE0C54C07A6AFB3126D53940815D1C18EE0C54C010CEB2D126D53940DC23E01DEE0C54C00043967727D53940FA5AC93CEF0C54C0C39A7F648ED539404BF6CE3AEF0C54C092383F0D8FD53940E3090531EF0C54C0AC0E6AB28FD539409F1AAF1FEF0C54C0D445364F90D53940D8714D07EF0C54C0ECBB3EDF90D539403F9C8FE8EE0C54C06F49605E91D5394067215CC4EE0C54C016CBF4C891D53940A778B69BEE0C54C02DE9EE1B92D5394064A5C96FEE0C54C0D9EDEE5492D5394065E3D541EE0C54C0BF7E657292D53940A02CDD25E70C54C0C2326A6993D53940
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the geometries to your question? So that I am sure that the result is the parcel you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ST_ConvexHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html)

```
SELECT building_group_id, 
       ST_ConvexHull(
         ST_Collect(geom))
FROM mylayer
GROUP BY building_group_id;
```

Comment: I think st_concaveHull might be better in this case - it will "shrink wrap" to the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I ran [st_concavehull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html):

```
SELECT 
    ST_ConcaveHull(ST_union(thegeom), 0.5) As geom
    FROM buildings As d
```

which gave me this:
[image: concave hull]

You can play with the "shrink factor", the smaller you make the number the more it will shrink but will take a lot longer to process...

For reference, st_convexhull gave me this:

[image]

Comment: i got same resullts....still I need as perfect pink as possible

Comment: I don't think it will get any closer. I ran it at 0.1 - it took 15 minutes and didn't get much better. I can't think of a better automatic way to get the outline you need.